# using position() in XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to transform following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<catalog>
    <cd QualifyingCode="1">
        <title>title1</title>
        <artist>artist1</artist>
    </cd>
    <cd QualifyingCode="1">
        <title>title2</title>
        <artist>artist2</artist>
    </cd>
    <cd QualifyingCode="2">
        <title>title3</title>
        <artist>artist3</artist>
    </cd>
    <cd QualifyingCode="2">
        <title>title4</title>
        <artist>artist4</artist>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

Using floowing XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">ID</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting the position as 1,2,3,4 using the position(). What I want is output for the position() should be 1,2,1,2 based on "QualifyingCode" attribute.

so my current output is :

```
My CD Collection
Title   Artist  ID
title1  artist1 1
title2  artist2 2
title3  artist3 3
title4  artist4 4
```

and my expected output is

```
 My CD Collection
    Title   Artist  ID
    title1  artist1 1
    title2  artist2 2
    title3  artist3 1
    title4  artist4 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use

```
   <td><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::cd[@QualifyingCode = current()/@QualifyingCode]) + 1"/></td>
```

Comment: will this work if QualifyingCode is not in the increament of 1? say i have QualifyingCode as "25" and "8"

Comment: The expression `count(preceding-sibling::cd[@QualifyingCode = current()/@QualifyingCode])` counts the number of preceding sibling `cd` elements which have the same `QualifyingCode` attribute value as the context node (which is the `cd` element processed by a `for-each` or matched by a template). So yes, assuming you want to count the elements having the same value, it works.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is output for the position() should be 1,2,1,2 based on
>   "QualifyingCode" attribute.

That's not a sufficiently clear requirement, and the example too is ambiguous. Assuming you want the numbering to restart whenever the QualifyingCode attribute **changes**, you should use `xsl:number`:

```
<xsl:number from="cd[@QualifyingCode!=preceding-sibling::cd[1]/@QualifyingCode]" level="any" />
```

Note that this is **not** the same as counting preceding siblings with the same QualifyingCode; the difference will become apparent if you append another cd with @QualifyingCode=1 to your current list.

Answer (score 0):

I've made two changes to your xslt:  one is that it's generally better to use a template rather than for-each.  The other specifically addresses you question by counting siblings that have the same `QualifyingCode`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">ID</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog/cd"/>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::cd[@QualifyingCode = 
             current()/@QualifyingCode]) + 1"/></td>
      </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ah, I see I was too slow in editing this answer.  Hope it's useful anyway.